# DELETE TOP variable records with variable from grouping of another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Say I have two tables: A and B

**Table A**

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 |    20 |
|  2 |    20 |
|  3 |    10 |
|  4 |     0 |
+----+-------+
```

**Table B**

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 |    20 |
|  2 |    10 |
|  3 |    30 |
|  4 |    20 |
|  5 |    20 |
|  6 |    10 |
+----+-------+
```

If I do `SELECT value, COUNT(*) AS occurrence FROM A GROUP BY value`, I'll get:

```
+-------+------------+
| value | occurrence |
+-------+------------+
|    20 |          2 |
|    10 |          1 |
|     0 |          1 |
+-------+------------+
```

Based on this grouping of table A, I want to delete `occurrence` records from table B with the same values. In other words, I want to delete from B 2 records with value 20, 1 record with value 10, and 1 record with value 0. (Other conditions include 'do nothing if no record exists' and 'smallest id first', but I think these conditions are pretty trivial compared to the bulk of this question.)

Table B after deleting should be:

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  3 |    30 |
|  5 |    20 |
|  6 |    10 |
+----+-------+
```

From the [official TOP documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), doesn't seems like I can perform some JOIN to use as the TOP expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `ROW_NUMBER` with CTEs here:

```
WITH cteA AS (
    SELECT value, COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM A
    GROUP BY value
),
cteB AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY value ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM B
)

DELETE
FROM cteB b
INNER JOIN cteA a
    ON b.value = a.value
WHERE
    b.rn <= a.cnt;
```

The logic here is that we use `ROW_NUMBER` to keep track of the order of each value in the B table.  Then, we join to bring in the counts of each value in the A table, and we only delete B records for which the row number is strictly less than or equal to the A count.

See the demo link below to verify that the logic be correct.  Note that I use a select there, not a delete, but the correct rows are being targeted for deletion.

### Demo

Comment: Will I improve the performance of this script if I only perform `ROW_NUMBER` with those in delete (assuming that is possible)? For example, if I perform `ROW_NUMBER` only on value 10 and 20 only and not 30 because 30 doesn't even appear in A.

Comment: I might depend on the data, and how much overlap there is.  To exclude data, you could use exists logic to first remove records which you know can't overlap.  Try comparing the explain plan of both versions.

Comment: For example if I change `FROM B` to `FROM B WHERE value IN (SELECT value FROM cteA)` would this be better in general?

Comment: Check the explain plan.  It depends on your data.  For data sets where most records overlap, it would probably hurt performance.